# React js Redirect Throttling history state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

Trying to perform redirect to private route after successful login and getting auth token from API and storing it in sessionStorage. In my main App component I am using Switch:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/cpanel' component={Cpanel} />
</Switch>
```

Private route is defined as follows:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

   <Route { ...rest } render = {(props) => (
       sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') === true
         ? <Component { ...props } />
         : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )} />
);
```

In my Login component handleSubmit function is as follows:

```
handleSubmit(event) {

    // preventing default form behaviour from submitting..
    event.preventDefault();

    // extracting form data and resetting form fields..
    const form = event.target;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    form.reset();

    // send post request to API..
    axios.post(this.state.uri, {
        email: data.get('email'),
        password: data.get('password')
    })
        .then((response) => {
            // save authorization token in client side..
            sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', response.data.id);
            this.setState({ token: response.data.id });
            console.log('Login successful! Authorization token id: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('authToken'));
            this.props.history.push('/cpanel');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

I guess it has something to do with 'this.props.history.push()' because in the render method of my Login component I put this code before returning JSX:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
    return <Redirect to='cpanel' />
} else {
    console.log('Your authorization token is not set..');
}
```

I really appreciate any answer since I have been trying to solve this issue on my own for 2 days. Thanks in advance! You all have a nice day!

Comment: By the way, I forgot to specify the nature of error: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: Any update on this?